# Session Value always equals last instance

Tags: php, html, session

I have a page that is running an SQL query. I am displaying information for each row that the query results in. I am now trying to implement a way to update the information for the things being displayed.

My understanding is that in order to get information from one page to another you need to use sessions.

My code is displaying the information from the MySQL tables, then underneath it is giving the user the choice to edit the information in a form then send it to another file

Comment: You are correct that your session is being replaced every loop. If you want, make `$_SESSION['toyid']` an array. The problem now is, how can your form tell what `toyid` to use? If you want, include the `toyid` in your form by putting it in a hidden input, instead of using `$_SESSION`

Comment: And of course, always use prepared statements. Don't just concatenate the value directly to the query

Comment: @CarlBinalla Yeah this is a long term project so I am working on all the little concatenate stuff and what not I just want to get it working first. Can you explain the hidden input idea?

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

Comment: @CarlBinalla Alright thanks for the idea! I also would like to try and figure out a way to use SESSION but I cannot quite wrap my head around it

Comment: That's fine too, just explore. You will be needing to make `$_SESSION['toyid']` an array to store all of the `toyid`, your problem, like I said, will be how to make your form select its own `toyid` from the array

Comment: @CarlBinalla I'll certainly be looking in to it. But for right this second the hidden type idea makes the code work properly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of easily doing this is to use [`<input type="hidden">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) so that you can include `$row['Toy_ID']` in your form.

Something like this:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
while ($row){

    echo "Toy Name: " . $row['Toy_Name'] . "<br>" . 
     "Store Name: . $row['Store_Name'] . "<br>" . 
     "Cost: " . $row['Cost'] . "";

    echo "<form action='update.php' method='post'>" . 
    "<input type='hidden' name='toyid' value='".$row['Toy_ID']."'>" . // here's the hidden input, which you can call by using `$_POST['toyid']`
    "<label>Toy Name: </label><input name='tname'; value='" . $row['Toy_Name'] . "'><br>" . 
    "<label>Store Name: </label><input name='storename'; value='" . $row['Store_Name'] . "'><br>" .
    "<label>Cost: </label><input name='cost'; value='" . $row['Cost'] . "'><br>" . 
    "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>" .            
    "</form></div><br><br>";


    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Then change your query to make use of `$_POST['toyid']` instead of `$_SESSION['toyid']`